# How to free dynamically allocated vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I tried to create vector of vector int, and I confused how do i free the dynamically allocated vector after.

The following is my code:

```
vector<int> *j;
vector< vector<int> > i;  //vector of vector<int>

int c;  //offset of the number
cin.ignore();
for(int count = 0; count < cas; count++ )
{
    c = 0;
    char line[1000];
    j = new vector<int>;
    cin.getline(line, 1000);
    //tokenize the input string which separate by space “　”
    char *p = strtok(line, " ");
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        n[c] = string(p);
        c++;
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    //convert the string input to integer for further calculation
    for(int m = 0; m < c; m++)
    {
        (*j).push_back(atoi(n[m].c_str()));
    }
    i.push_back(*j);
}

//this is the way i try to free the allocated vector, and i get segmentation fault for this
    j = &i[0];
    delete [] j;
```

Comment: Why do you need to dynamically allocate it on the first place? There is no reason.

Comment: `vector< vector<int> >` is holding a list of vector not vector pointer, and `std::vector` will manage the memory of the object get pushed into it.

Comment: It would be better to not use `new` in the first place. Change `j` to `vector<int> j;` and the loop body to `j.push_back(10); i.push_back( std::move(j) );`.

Comment: @slave um because inside the for loop, i need to change the contend of the vector, then i will need a new container for the new info

Comment: @FoulQue that's not a reason, yuou can do that with local variable.

Comment: @FoulQua: Also, there's `std::vector< T >::clear( )` which resets the vector content, but reuses the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any pointers or `new` or `delete`. These are advanced concepts that have no place in this simple program.

```
vector<vector<int>> i;

for (...) { 
    vector<int> j;
    // fill up j
    i.push_back(j);
}
```

Remember, a vector of vectors is not conceptually different from a vector of ints. You don't start new'ing and delete'ing ints when you need to fill up a `vector<int>`. Nor do you need to do so for any `X` when you work with a `vector<X>`.

Comment: The above program can be rewritten so that it doesn't use `j` or `push_back`, can you find a way?

Comment: oh isee... you saying because it's vector of vector, i can simply do like i[offset].push_back(number). but i still need to specify the size of the i at the beginning (eg. vector< vector<int>> i(100) )  right? Thanks so much, i didn't think of that before.　@n.m.

Comment: You can call `resize` on the outer vector at the beginning of the loop. `i.resize(i.size()+1);` If you do that, you can use `i.back().push_back(number)` (back returns a reference to the last element).

Answer (score 1):

The

```
i.push_back(*j);
```

does't push the pointer; it makes a copy of the vector.

As soon as you've done that, you can

```
delete j;
```

there and then.

(Of course if you change `i` to store *pointers*, the story will be completely different.)

Comment: doesn't seem like makes a copy but pushing a reference to the vector, because after i.push_back(*j), I do delete j.  After the for loop, i tried to access the contend with i[0][0] then I get segmentation fault. Can you explain this a little bit? Thanks. @NPE

Comment: @FoulQua: You're doing something else wrong that you have not shown in your code or explained to us.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley ok, i updated the code i have for now, can you look it up?

Comment: @FoulQua: You're neither deleting j after `i.push_back(*j);`, nor accessing `i[0][0]` in that code.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley ok. i don't know why i get seg fault before, but now it seems works out. thanks for your help

Comment: @FoulQua: Good. But change the code in your question back to its broken form, otherwise this answer doesn't make any sense (through no fault of its author).